# Android App force stop in emulator when add a dialog

Tags: android

My App works totally fine until I added a new feature that checks internet connection availability and display an alert dialog box if internet isn't available. When I run my code in emulator without checking internet it works fine but when I use to verify `internet connection` using the same code as I provided below it show me a `force close` dialog with OK button I have tried all different solutions available on internet but nothing works for me. I am new to Android development and don't know though things but according to my research I am surely missing something in my code but unfortunately I am unable to figure it out.

Here is my **Main Activity**

```
package com.testapp.mytestapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import java.io.File;
import static com.testapp.mytestapp.R.*;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private FrameLayout customViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
    private View mCustomView;
    private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {

            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, style.AlertDialogCustom).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Communication Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Please make sure that internet connection is active.");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            AppRater appRater = new AppRater(this);
            appRater.setDaysBeforePrompt(1);
            appRater.setLaunchesBeforePrompt(3);
            appRater.setPhrases("Rate This App",
                    "If you like our App don't forget to rate our application on Google Play. Thanks for your support!",
                    "Rate Now", "Later", "Ignore");
            appRater.setTargetUri("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            appRater.show();
            customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
            webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
            mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
            webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
            webView.loadUrl("https://custom-domain-name.com/test-page.html");
        }
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if (inCustomView()) {
                hideCustomView();
                return true;
            }

            if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
           onShowCustomView(view, callback);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mCustomView = view;
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.addView(view);
            customViewCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            mCustomView = null;
        }
    }

    class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("custom-domain-name.com")) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            trimCache(); //if trimCache is static
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void trimCache() {
        try {
            File dir = getCacheDir();
            if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                deleteDir(dir);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return dir.delete();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.testapp.mytestapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my layout's **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/customViewContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my layout's **video_progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/progress_indicator"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ProgressBar android:id="@android:id/progress"
                 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:paddingTop="5dip"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:text="loading"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my **styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <color name="basic_blue1">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="basic_blue2">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="basic_blue3">#9954BB</color>
    <color name="basic_orange1">#2780E3</color>
    <color name="basic_orange2">#2780E3</color>
    <color name="basic_white1">#eeffffff</color>
    <color name="basic_white2">#99ffffff</color>

    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="app_rater" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What version of the emulator do you have?

Comment: @diegoveloper its Nexus 4 API 22

Comment: Look at the stack trace to determine the cause of the crash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173.

Comment: I put my answer below

Comment: @diegoveloper let me check and execute again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the crash is because you need to get references of your views before your condition , because you are using your `webview` object in onResume/onPause/onStop methods, therefore when you don't have internet your `webview` object is null.

move this lines before the if/else :

```
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Comment: Oh man you have saved my day thank you soo much I really appriciate your kindness I have no words to thank you that you saved me from a big problem God Bless you :)

Comment: no problem man, I'm glad to help you. Don't forget LogCat is your friend :)

Comment: sure I will use it every time and as I said i am new to android world :)